# Inherent math operation in Java

Tags: java-8, symbolic-math

I'm writing essentially a small calaculator where you input two numbers, an operand like "+, -, *, /" etc and it'll preform that function.

My initial thoughts have been to just have the variables get entered by the user, than just have them computed as imputed. I would like to do it this way, as to avoid writing several `if` `else` statements and keeping things a bit cleaner. But I can't find a place explaining how to inherently compute the values and imputed characters.

```
package hw2p1;

import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.script.*;

public class Calculator {
public static void PrintCalculator(){

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    double num1; //1st entered number 
    double num2; //2nd entered number
    String val1; //Math operator like + - * /.
    double math1; //the results.
    String equation = "";


    System.out.print("Enter the first number:"); 
        num1 = input.nextDouble();
    System.out.print("Enter the second number:"); 
        num2 = input.nextDouble(); 
    System.out.print("Enter an operator:");
        val1 = input.next();
```

I know this is incomplete, but I don't know/can't find the logic on how to  string the three inputted values together and compute them.

Comment: Could you set up a switch statement and perform operations accordingly?

Comment: When you say "inherently compute the values" are you looking to try to execute a string as source code? You could use a [`ScriptEngine` to run JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14320308/5743988)...

Comment: What do you mean by "inherently compute the values"?

Comment: @AndrewL. Yes I am allowed to use a switch statement. I just do not have enough experience to know how to use one, or if it's the right thing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Sorry, my phrasing was super weird. Essentially, do I have to explicitly state that "+" means addition, or can it be already interpreted as a sign of addition?

Answer (score 1):

I could not remove `if-else` but may be you can try something like this

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result = operate("+").applyAsInt(10, 20);
    System.out.println(result);
}

private static IntBinaryOperator operate(String op){
    switch(op){
    case "+": return Math::addExact;
    case "-": return Math::subtractExact;
    //other cases
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("incorrect operator");
}
```

One issue though, `Math` do not have methods for double

Comment: I've never seen `::` in Java. Is this something new in Java 8?

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't get that to work on my end. Also, this is outside of the main method because its gets called on by another file.

Comment: The two upfront ones would be that I'm getting errors saying that operate is referring to the missing type BitFunction. And `Math::addExact` - "the target of this expression must be a functional interface." Also what I'm working on is beginner level stuff and I don't think it would be asking for this kind of solution right off the bat. But I legit don't know.

Comment: You may use `IntBinaryOperator` instead, or for boxed values, `BinaryOperator<Integer>`…

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be

```
public static double calculate(double a, String op, double b) {
    switch(op) {
        case "+": return a+b;
        case "-": return a-b;
        case "*": return a*b;
        case "/": return a/b;
        case "%": return a%b;
        case "^": return Math.pow(a, b);
        default: throw new IllegalArgumentException("no such operator '"+op+"'");
    }
}
```

which is semantically equivalent to a sequence of `if`-`else` statements, but clearly showing the intention and potentially more efficient, though there’s not much worth in speculating about performance here.

It can be invoked like

```
double math1 = calculate(num1, val1, num2); //the results.
```

but you really should retink your variable naming scheme. If you have to append a comment telling the purpose behind every declaration, you’re clearly doing something wrong. Why not naming the variables, e.g. `firstInputNumber`, `secondInputNumber`, `operator` and `result` in the first place? Then, you don’t need the comments telling the variable’s purposes.

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr**

You have to explicitly state that "+" means addition.

**Long Anwser**

When the user types something when your program runs, all of it is just characters. It's up to your program to interpret those characters to do something meaningful. `Scanner` can be helpful with this because it knows how to interpret the characters `1234` as an `int`. However, beyond data for the built-in types, `Scanner` is completely dumb.

In building your own calculator program, you are basically writing a simplified version of the Java compiler. The compiler is a program which reads characters from a file and converts them into something that can execute on a Java Virtual Machine. You will do much of the same thing in your own calculator program. This means that you have to explicitly write the rules that interpret characters that represent mathematical operators into the operations that they actually perform.

If you are interested in learning more about this topic, you can do some research on compilers and interpreters. They are generally made of two pieces: the lexical analyzer, or lexer, and the parser. This is all especially necessary if you want to allow the user to type in a complete mathematical expression like `2 + 3` rather than prompting them for each piece of the expression individually.

I hope this gives you some terminology that you can use in a Google search.

Comment: I think it might help. I'm fairly sure I'll be using multiple if else statements. Unfortunately I can't get them to behave properly either, but that seems like a topic for a different question.